# I don't know why the socket's connecting is increasing in nodeJS with socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Each time I access the page(F5 ect..), the number of socket connections increases.

ouput

```
(1)
re
connect

(2) - F5 or RegetPage after backspace
disconnect
re
connect
connect

(3)
re
disconnect
disconnect
connect
connect
connect
```

It seems to me that the connection to the socket is not closing, but pausing

My Code

server.js

```
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    req.io = io;
    next();
});

const temp = require("./routes/temp");
app.use("/temp", temp);
```

temp.js

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => controller.getPage(req, res, req.io));
```

function getPage of controller

```
getPage(req, res, io){
    console.log('re');
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      console.log('connect');
      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnect');
        socket.disconnect(0);
      });
    });
    //action
  }
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are attaching new connection and disconnect listeners whenever the page is loaded. Those listeners are not per socket so you only need to do it once, not for every page request. So you could move that part to your `server.js`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I have a question.
if I don't use the socket, Is there no cost?
Example, Do I write socket codes on the server when I have 1 million pages and use sockets only on one page?

Comment: @재창킴 Not sure I understand your question. A socket is a single connection to a client. You can use it to communicate with specific clients using `socket.on`, or you can do things like `io.on` to communicate with all clients the same way. You'd need to explain your use case for me to help you more.

Comment: @재창킴 Also, if this solution helped you, please mark is as the answer so it can help others.